# WPF MVVM Binding of itemssource to an ObservableCollection inside a different class and add items to it

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I have integrated a small application with a console window that passes information to the user.

In my view there is an ItemControl having a TextBlock as template showing the "ConsoleText" with the desired color "FontColour":

```
<Window x:Class="MyApplication.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:helper="clr-namespace:MyApplication.Helpers"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="600" Width="800" MinHeight="600" MinWidth="800">


    <Grid>
        <DockPanel Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Grid.RowSpan="4" Background="Black">
            <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" helper:ScrollViewerExtension.AutoScroll="True">
                <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding logger.ConsoleOutput}">
                    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding ConsoleText}" Foreground="{Binding FontColour}" FontSize="14"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                </ItemsControl>
            </ScrollViewer>
        </DockPanel>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

My code behind file only contains the DataContext:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = new MainWindowViewModel();
    }
}
```

My ViewMode for the view has three information:

1. Instantiate MyLogicClass, which is structured in another project and which is given as reference.
2. ConsoleOutputList is instantiated to be able to display "ConsoleOutput" in the view later on.
3. The button is not displayed in the view because it is not relevant in the view and it works without any problems.

And here the ViewModel:

```
public class MainWindowViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    MyLogicClass myLogicClass = new MyLogicClass(null);
    ConsoleOutputList logger = new ConsoleOutputList();

    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        MyButtonCommand = new RelayCommand(o => Task.Run(() => myLogicClass.Test()));
    }
    
    public ICommand MyButtonCommand { get; }
}
```

ConsoleOutputList contains an ObservableCollection from "ConsoleLine" (also in another project).
The "ConsoleLine" may have a string and a SolidColorBrush in the ctor (I think this one is not relevant either).

```
public class ConsoleOutputList : ObservableObject
{
    public ConsoleOutputList()
    {
        ConsoleOutput = new ObservableCollection<ConsoleLine>();
        
        // For testing purposes I add a random entry to see if the binding in general works - but this doesn`t work neither
        ConsoleOutput.Add(new ConsoleLine("Test", Brushes.Green));
    }

    public ObservableCollection<ConsoleLine> consoleOutput { get; set; }

    public ObservableCollection<ConsoleLine> ConsoleOutput
    {
        get
        {
            return consoleOutput;
        }
        set
        {
            consoleOutput = value;
        }
    }

    //Used to add new lines to the ObservableCollection
    public void WriteToConsole(object msg, SolidColorBrush fontColour)
    {
        ConsoleOutput.Add(new ConsoleLine(msg, fontColour));
    }

}
```

This classe is used for all application logic (also in another project).
As a test I have here the method Test() to simply add a text.

```
public class MyLogicClass
{
    ConsoleOutputList Logger = new ConsoleOutputList();
    
    public void Test()
    {
        Logger.WriteToConsole($"Test", Brushes.Gray);
    }

}
```

Now I have two problems:

1. I add a new element in ctor of ConsoleOutputList as a test to see in general if my view works correctly => But does not work
2. I have the Test() method to simply test adding new items to the ObservableCollection to see if they show up after being added => But of course also does not work

And yes I know - I create two instances of ConsoleOutputList and this is not correct (this is the reason for the second problem).
But I don`t know how to do it better because I need to access the WriteToConsole() from everywhere in the code. (Maybe change to static?)
But how do I solve then the first problem and how does it then works with static property and showing them up in the view.

Update:
Even if I change everything to static the "Test" line is shown in green but everything which I add afterwards is not shown in the GUI:
[Visual Studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SbIPK.png)

Comment: You create new instances a two places `new ConsoleOutputList()`. Do this in only place only. Also: please translate the remaining parts of your question to English, too.

Comment: @KlausGütter yes I know. I updated the description. But first problem which should be solved is how to show them in the view :).

Comment: `ItemsSource="{Binding logger.ConsoleOutput}"` will not work because logger is 1) private and 2) not a property, but a field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In WPF you can't bind to methods or fields. You must bind to a public property (see [Microsoft Docs: Binding source types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/data/binding-sources-overview?view=netdesktop-6.0#binding-source-types) to learn more about the supported binding sources).

To fix issue 1) you must implement the `MainWindowViewModel.logger` field as public property. If the property is expected to change, it must raise the `INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged` event.

To fix 2), you must distribute a shared instance of `ConsoleOutputList` throughout your application. To expose it as a static instance is one solution, but generally not recommended. The better solution is to pass a shared instance to the constructor of the each type that depends on `ConsoleOutputList`.

The fixed solution could look as follows:

**MainWindowViewModel.cs**

```cs
public class MainWindowViewModel : ObservableObject
{
  public MainWindowViewModel(ConsoleOutputList logger, MyLogicClass myLogicClass)
  {
    this.Logger = logger;  
    this.MyLogicClass = myLogicClass;
    this.MyButtonCommand = new RelayCommand(o => Task.Run(() => myLogicClass.Test()));
  }
    
  public ConsoleOutputList Logger { get; }
  public ICommand MyButtonCommand { get; }
  private MyLogicClass MyLogicClass { get; }
}
```

**MyLogicClass.cs**

```cs
public class MyLogicClass
{
  private ConsoleOutputList Logger { get; }

  public MyLogicClass(ConsoleOutputList logger) => this.Logger = logger;
    
  public void Test()
  {
    this.Logger.WriteToConsole($"Test", Brushes.Gray);
  }
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```cs
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
  public MainWindow(MainWindowViewModel mainWindowViewModel)
  {
    InitializeComponent();

    this.DataContext = mainWindowViewModel;
  }
}
```

**App.xaml**

```xml
<Application Startup="App_OnStartup">
</Application>
```

**App.xaml.cs**

```cs
public partial class App : Application
{
  private void App_OnStartup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
  {
    /** Initialize the application with the shared instance **/
    var sharedLoggerInstance = new ConsoleOutputList();
    var classThatNeedsLogger = new MyLogicClass(sharedLoggerInstance);
    var mainViewModel = new MainWindowViewModel(sharedLoggerInstance, classThatNeedsLogger);
    var mainWindow = new MainWindow(mainViewModel);
    
    mainWindow.Show();
  }
}
```

Also don't wrap the `ItemsControl` into a `ScrollViewer`. Use a `ListBox` instead. `ListBox` is an enhanced `ItemsControl`, that has a `ScrollViewer` and UI virtualization enabled by default. If you expect to generate many log entries you will end up with many items in the list. If you don't use UI virtualization, your `ItemsControl` will kill the performance/responsiveness of your GUI.

```xml
<DockPanel>
  <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Logger.ConsoleOutput}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
      ...
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
  </ListBox>
</DockPanel>
```

To allow updating the collection `ConsoleOutput` from a background thread or a non UI thread in general, you can either use the `Dispatcher` to update the collection (not recommended in this case):

```cs
Dispatcher.InvokeAsync(() => myCollection.Add(item));
```

or configure the binding engine to marshal the collection's `CollectionChanged` event to the dispatcher thread.
Since the critical object is a collection that serves as a binding source, I recommend to configure the binding engine by calling the static `BindingOperations.EnableCollectionSynchronization` method. It is essential that the method is invoked on the dispatcher thread:

**ConsoleOutputList.cs**

```cs
public class ConsoleOutputList : ObservableObject
{
  private object SyncLock { get; }

  public ConsoleOutputList()
  { 
    this.SyncLock = new object();
    this.ConsoleOutput = new ObservableCollection<ConsoleLine>();
    
    // Configure the binding engine to marshal the CollectionChanged event 
    // of this collection to the UI thread to prevent cross-thread exceptions
    BindingOperations.EnableCollectionSynchronization(this.ConsoleOutput, this.SyncLock);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you it works perfectly! But just one info and one additional question: 1) remove "()" from mainWindowViewModel since it is not a method 2) I have the problem that the gui doesn`t update after adding a new entry to ConsoleOutput

Comment: 1) Thanks. I wrote the code here in the editor without compiler support, so that one skipped my attention. 2) How and where do you update the CosoleOutput? Does adding the value in constructor of ConsoleOutput works? Note that the ConsoleOutput property is defined wrong. The property must be backed up by a private field: get returns the field and set sets the field. Currently the property is backed up by another property (at least in the code from your question).

Comment: Sorry to the second point. The "test" text in the ctor of ConsoleOutputList is shown in view. So die Binding works in general. Just everything which I add afterwards e.g. by calling Test() are not shown. But what I have noticed in addition is this:  However, when I switch from ListBox to ItemsControl or the other way around at runtime, the added items are present.

Comment: I have checked your code again. I found this problematic line in the view model constructor: `this.MyButtonCommand = new RelayCommand(o => Task.Run(() => myLogicClass.Test()));` Invoking this command should crash your application. This code is causing a cross-thread exception. You should not invoke code that manipulates UI on a background thread. Please remove the Task.Run from the command delegate. Let me know if this fixed your current issue too.

Comment: There is no need for a background thread. Adding an item to the collection is not a longrunning CPU or IO task.

Comment: And what is the alternative of Task.Run without freezing the gui? But it worked after removing Task.Run but I didn`t run into an exception.

Comment: You don't need a extra thread if updating the collection is all you do. If you experience anny issues while updating the collection then this is related to using the ItemsControl. I think you have posted the same question before and I recommended to you to remove the ScrollViewer and then replace the ItemsControl with a ListBox. The ListBox is an enhanced ItemsControl that offers scrolling and, most important, UI virtualization by default. UI virtualization means that only the visible items are loaded. The ItemsControl loads all items even when they are not visible, what results in bad perform

Comment: Yes you`re right but in my Test() Method I just add something. But at other points I have a huge logic which maybe takes a little bit more time where it freezes.

Comment: I have added an example that shows how you how to configure the binding engine to marshal the CollectionChanged event to the UI thread. Using the last example allows you to update the collection from any thread.

Comment: Thank you. With some modification it works!

Comment: Ah, sorry. I forgot the lock object. I have updated the example.